# TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature for ARIMA model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels, arima

I trying to do ARIMA model analysis on a series extracted from the following pandas DataFrame

```
CpcGDP.tail()

               65
2012-01-01  2593.23
2013-01-01  2591.06
2014-01-01  2608.38
2015-01-01  2665.35
2016-01-01  2724.4
```

I first convert objects

```
CpcGDP.convert_objects(convert_numeric= True)
```

Then get the series and convert to float

```
Cdx = CpcGDP.columns[0]
S = CpcGDP.loc[:, Cdx]
S.astype(float)
```

Then do the analysis

```
 mod = sm.tsa.ARIMA(S.astype(float), order= (0,2,1))
 result = mod.fit()
```

But I getthe following error

```
 TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Can you help me solve this error, please?

Comment: You need to show more of the traceback so we see where it fails. This way we cannot guess where a string concatenation with unicode fails. Something is an array instead of a string in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error doing the same stuff.
For me the solution was using pandas `Series` instead of `Dataframe`